# Automate clicks in WPF window from external script

Tags: python, c#, automation, automated-tests, ironpython

Is it possible to create a script in Python or IronPython that automatically clicks on some widgets of an open WPF (C#) window? 
It would be a task that would solve my life but I have no idea where to start.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Autoit, pyautogui, pywinauto and clicknium, all these libraries support automating WPF applications.
You may need to use tools like uispy and inspect to help you locate the control if you are using pyautogui and pywinauto.
Sample code for pywinauto looks like below:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend='uia').start("notepad.exe")
main = app.window(title='*Untitled - Notepad', control_type='Window')
closeBtn=main.child_window(title="Close", control_type='Button')
closeBtn.click_input()
```

You can install clicknium vscode extension to help you locate the control if you are using clicknium.
Sample code looks like below:

```
from clicknium import locator, ui
ui(locator.notepad.button_close).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google search revealed the following tutorial:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mouse-keyboard-automation-using-python/

If you are dead set on using python or any code for that matter, a simple macro recorder may give you more faster:

https://www.macrorecorder.com/

This does not account for any deviation in the application or OS. If another popup or window is open, the script/macro will just continue happily. If you are after UI testing, you may want to look at professional UI test tools.

Answer (score 0):

you can see [this example](https://github.com/clicknium/clicknium-samples/tree/main/EmployeeDataMigration), demonstrate one automation case for both desktop application and web application.